# I Need to Write the Same mySQL Query Twice

Tags: php, mysql

Near the top of a PHP page I have a mySQL query followed by a do-while loop.

```
$query_offer = "SELECT offer, offer_text FROM ad_offers WHERE hid LIKE '$hid' AND show_from < CURRENT_DATE() AND show_to > CURRENT_DATE()";
$offer = mysql_query($query_offer, $MySQL_extranet) or die(mysql_error());
$row_offer = mysql_fetch_assoc($offer);
do {
SOME PHP STUFF
}while($row_offer = mysql_fetch_assoc($offer));
```

Then further down the page I want to repeat the same do-while loop with different PHP code inside it. But it doesn't work. It seems as if the system has forgotten the results of the query after doing the first do-while. If I precede the second do-while with a repeat of the original query, it works. But that seems very messy, and surely it is unnecessary to write the same query twice on the same page.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The fetch_assoc moves an inner pointer to the next line, so after the loop you are on the last line, run the query again so the "pointer" goes to the begin. Or you can use mysql_result($offer, $line)

Comment: You are overwriting the `$row_offer` during the while..... this will overwrite the mysql_fetch_Assoc

Comment: Of course the system forgets the result after you're done with fetching the results. Store it in an array if you need to use it again. And rebuild that do/while into a proper while since that's how you're using it.

Comment: @demonofnight He doesn't need to run the query again...just reset the result. `mysql_data_seek($offer, 0)` Better yet is to assign to an array after the first pass through.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the rows to an array then reuse the array

```
$Offers = array();
while($row_offer = mysql_fetch_assoc($offer)) {
     $Offers[] = $row_offer;
}
```

then further down your code loop over $Offers

Comment: This solution inserts a sparse NULL at the head of the array.

Comment: Shouldn't be using a `do/while`

Comment: I really want to know who is teaching all these people to use the `do/while` loop for everything. It has extremely limited appropriate usage, yet, most beginners seem to latch on to it and use it exclusively. (in reference to OP, not you Patrick)

Comment: @crush, the reason I use do/while is because it is in the PHP manual and it works. Why do you think I shouldn't be using it, and what should I use instead?

Comment: @TrapezeArtist, in this instance you shouldnt use it as it will fill the first array item with a NULL, as NielsKeurentjes mentioned before i fixed my code. do/while is for when you already have a beginning value and the loop somehow manipulates that value and then needs to check it it against your condition.

Comment: As I said, do/while has a very limited usage scenario.

Answer (score 1):

after looping the data once, you need to do

```
mysql_data_seek($offer, 0);
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

**Note:** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Assign the results to an array and iterate over that again, or create function which you can call whenever you need it.

```
<?php
function getOffers($hid) {
    $offers = array();
    $query  = mysql_query('SELECT ...');
    while($offer = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        array_push($offers, $offer);
    }
    return $offers;
}

$offers = getOffers($hid);

// use $offers here

// or here

// or recall getOffers($hid)
```

Anthony.

Comment: I wouldnt suggest recalling the function, thats an additional query that doesnt need to be executed unless $hid is a different value from before.